# Ocaml compile multiple files (circular dependencies)

Tags: dependencies, compilation, ocaml, circular-dependency

I have downloaded `xml-light` for ocaml and try to compile it, but it has never been succeeded, the problem is as follow.

When I input `ocamlopt dtd.ml`, there will be an error `Unbound module Xml`.
Then I input `ocamlopt xml.ml`, there will be an error `Unbound value XmlParser.make`.
Then I input `ocamlopt xmlParser.ml`, there will be an error `Unbound module Dtd`.

is there actually a way to compile them together? I feel so stupid because of this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not so trivial, nothing surprising. Here is the output of `make` (from mingw/cygwin ocaml distribution):

```
ocamlyacc xml_parser.mly
ocamlc  xml.mli
ocamlc  dtd.mli
ocamlc  xml_parser.mli
ocamlc  -c xml_parser.ml
ocamllex xml_lexer.mll
ocamlc  xml_lexer.mli
ocamlc  -c xml_lexer.ml
ocamlc  -c dtd.ml
ocamlc  xmlParser.mli
ocamlc  -c xmlParser.ml
ocamlc  -c xml.ml
ocamlc -o xml-light.cma -a  xml_parser.cmo xml_lexer.cmo dtd.cmo xmlParser.cmo xml.cmo
```

And the test:

```
ocamlc xml-light.cma test.ml -o test.exe
```

`make install` output:

```
ocamlopt  -c xml_parser.ml
ocamlopt  -c xml_lexer.ml
ocamlopt  -c dtd.ml
ocamlopt  -c xmlParser.ml
ocamlopt  -c xml.ml
ocamlopt -o xml-light.cmxa -a  xml_parser.cmx xml_lexer.cmx dtd.cmx xmlParser.cmx xml.cmx

cp xml-light.cmxa xml-light.a xml-light.cma xml.mli xmlParser.mli dtd.mli xml.cmi xmlParser.cmi dtd.cmi xml.cmx dtd.cmx xmlParser.cmx `ocamlc -where`
```

Note the last line (i've separated it with newline): you probably won't have cp command; just create `%OCAMLLIB%\xml-light` directory manually and copy listed files there. Then you can build your project like this:

```
ocamlopt -I +xml-light xml-light.cmxa foo.ml -o foo.exe
```

Comment: @barti: you help me again... anyway, there is still a thing cannot be finished so far. When I put this file in my project folder, then I want to open this file using `open Xml;;` for example, why did it give me an error message: `Error: xml.cmi is not a compiled interface`, what else did I miss here?

Comment: @barti: is there no way to do this on IDE? I use `Camelia` and that error happened when I use the IDE and type `open Xml;;` or any other file

Comment: @zfm: anyway, you have to put library files to appropriate directories, don't think an IDE will help you there... This particular library is much easier to build with mingw (not without glitches, though)

Comment: @barti: I believe I had it in the right directory... let's say, if I type `open Asdf;;` in which I don't have `asdf.cmi'`, the error would be `Error: Unbound module Asdf`. So it has detected the right folder, the right `.cmi`, but it thought differently, and I don't understand why.

Comment: @zfm: let's narrow your problem to `xml-light`, ok? :) What error do you get when you `open Xml`?

Comment: @barti: the one I wrote above, `Error: xml.cmi is not a compiled interface`

Comment: @zfm: good :) what options are passed to compiler when you build the project?

Comment: @barti: I just used the one you wrote above.

Comment: @barti: I finally managed to handle this. Sorry for bothering you too much. I had OCaml 3.11 and now using OCaml 3.12, my other stupidness is, my `bin` is still targeted into the old OCaml while my IDE has been targeted into the new one, and it creates a chaos. Now everything is fine, thank you very much!

Comment: @zfm: good. What files do you have in `d:\ocaml\lib\xml-light` (writing path from memory, adjust it to actual ocaml installation)? Give full listing.

Comment: @zfm: and one thing for future: don't accept answers until it works for you actually, it is fair.

Comment: @barti: I dont need file to be in `d:\ocaml\lib\xml-light` now. I can set my path (on the IDE) to wherever my `.cmo` and `.cmi` are :)

Comment: @zfm: yes, you can; however, it helps to keep the system tidy :)

Comment: @zfm: you can look at ocamlopt manual http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/manual025.html (specifically `-I` switch) for path resolution, if interested; cheers